# Reduce window width and keep current columns size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap I want to be able to leave an extra column on the right side of the page so:

```
<div class="row"><div class="col-md-push-1 col-md-10"> Content Goes Here </div></div>
```

The problem is that even though I had left 1 col available it shrinks the content in the center anyways as I reduce the size of the window. I want to be able to keep the content centralize and to not shrink until the window width is small enough. What is the best solution for this?[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-1-md hidden-sm"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10"> Content Goes Here </div>
</div>
```

the class `hidden-*` hides the content at a specific bootstrap width

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that the content in the center still shrinks even though that there is available margin on the left and right of the content.

Comment: can you show me the content or tell me what elements you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend media queries to change the width of the row div. Media queries can be used to specify CSS based on screen width.

```
.container {
    width:600px;
  }

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    width:100%;
  }
```

So the HTML markup may look like

```
<div class="row container">
    <div class="col-md-push-1 col-md-10"> Content Goes Here </div>
</div>
```

What will happen in this example is that when the width is 600px or less, the wrapping div will scale as the page size changes, but above 600px, the div will stay at a fixed width.

https://www.bootply.com/SwAc2a0RgF

Answer (score 0):

The **best** way to handle this is to use the [**built-in functions**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-offsetting) for handling offsets in Bootstrap, with the syntax `.col-XX-offset-X`:

```css
.col-xs-10 {
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10">Content Goes Here</div>
</div>
```

A Bootstrap row is **always** comprised of 12 columns, and by utilising `col-xs-offset-1` in conjunction with `col-xs-10`, the above example automatically provides even offsets on either side of the column.

Hope this helps! :)